# Select intersection of two query ordered by sum of a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three table as follows:

```
documents (id, content) 
words (id, word) 
word_document (word_id, document_id, count)
```

Words table have all the words occurred in all documents and word_document relate a word to a document and the count of that word in that document.

I want to write a query to search for two words and returns only the documents which have both word ordered by the sum of the count of both words in documents.

For example

```
DocA: green apple is not blue
DocB: blue apple is blue
DocC: red apple is red
```

now a search for **apple** and **blue** returns:

```
DocA, 3
DocB, 2
```

becaus:

```
DocA contains both words and 3 of them
DocB contains both words and 2 of them
DocC only contains one word
```

I used **intersect** successfully but it doesn't return the count sum and no order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who want this, this only works:

```
select wd.document_id, (wd.count + d.count) as tcount from word_document as wd
join words as w on w.id = wd.word_id
join
(select document_id, count from word_document 
join words on words.id = word_document.word_id
where words.word = "apple") d on d.document_id=wd.document_id
where w.word = "blue" order by tcount desc
```

You can create temp table from the inner query and execute outer on that. It can be done recursively for more words.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it I think:

```
select a.document_id, a.count + b.count
from 
(
 select document_id, count
 from word_document
 where word_id = 'apple'
 group by document_id
) a 
INNER JOIN 
(
 select document_id, count
 from word_document
 where word_id = 'blue'
 group by document_id
) b 
ON a.document_id = b.document_id
ORDER BY a.count + b.count
```

Comment: Mahmoud answer worked for me, I don't know the performance of which one is better. But I think his is better as it query the word_document once!